# Determine number of processes in a MPMD for each program

Tags: mpi

Is it possible to know from the program how many processes are executing `prog_1` and `prog_2` ?

> `mpirun -np 3 prog_1 : -np 5 prog_2`

I mean, how can I know inside prog_1 that is being executed by 3 processes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do not think there is a straightforward and portable way to achieve this.
the program name is in `argv[0]`, so you can `MPI_Gather()` them and `MPI_Bcast()` or `MPI_Scatter()` the info you need.

an other approach is to start with the first program only, and then `MPI_Comm_spawn()` the second program.

Comment: argv only contain the string in front of the executable (and the name of the executable) so -np 3 will not appear there (i am understanding correctly your idea ?).  I am trying to avoid using MPI_Comm_spawn.

Comment: that is why you need to `MPI_Gather()` all the `argv[0]`, then you can figure out how many programs and how many instances of each program is running

Comment: now I understand, thank you for this new explanation !